# ¿Como puedo usar esta sentencia Mysql en Mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Al ya no tener soporte las versiones antiguas de php, estoy migrando mis proyectos a MYSQLI y tengo un problema, no se como agruparlos en un array, pues mi anterior codigo era este:

```
$enero = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(kg_panela) AS r FROM dia_batido WHERE MONTH(fecha)=1 AND YEAR(fecha)='$año'"));
```

Alguna ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría algo así:

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','basededatos');

$sql = "SELECT SUM(kg_panela) AS r FROM dia_batido WHERE MONTH(fecha)=1 AND YEAR(fecha)='$año'";

$query = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

$enero = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
```